# Change currency dynamically on Laravel Cashier-stripe

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I'm setting up an ecommerce website that allows user to purchase in different currencies (COP,GBP,USD,EUR), is it possible that the user gets charged in his chosen currency? i'm using Cashier-stripe but I can't find how to change the currency dinamically on its documentation.
Im using the 12.14 version